# How can JavaScript save to a local file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

There's already a solution for writing file JSON online but I want to save json file locally.
I've tried to use this example http://jsfiddle.net/RZBbY/10/
It creates a link to download the file, using this call
`a.attr('href', 'data:application/x-json;base64,' + btoa(t.val())).show();`
Is there a way to save the file locally instead of providing a downloadable link?
There are other types of conversion beyond `data:application/x-json;base64`?

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com//jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/demos.css">        
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>a { font: 12px Arial; color: #ac9095; }</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
var f = $('form'), a = $('a'),
    i = $('input'), t = $('textarea');
       
$('#salva').click(function() {
    var o = {}, v = t.val();
    
    a.hide();//nasconde il contenuto
    i.each(function() { 
    o[this.name] = $(this).val(); });
    if (v === '') {
        t.val("[\n " + JSON.stringify(o) + " \n]")         
    }
    else {
        t.val(v.substr(0, v.length - 3));
        t.val(t.val() + ",\n " + JSON.stringify(o) +  " \n]")  
    }
});
});

$('#esporta').bind('click', function() {
    a.attr('href', 'data:application/x-json;base64,' + btoa(t.val())).show();
        
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>Nome</label> <input type="text" name="nome"><br />
        <label>Cognome</label> <input type="text" name="cognome">
        <button type="button" id="salva">Salva</button>
    </form>        

    <textarea rows="10" cols="60"></textarea><br />
    <button type="button" id="esporta">Esporta dati</button>
    <a href="" style="display: none">Scarica Dati</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 35):

Based on http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html:

```
var fileContent = "My epic novel that I don't want to lose.";
var bb = new Blob([fileContent ], { type: 'text/plain' });
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = 'download.txt';
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(bb);
a.click();
```

Modified the original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9av2mfjx/

Comment: Add `a.remove();` at the end of the code.

Answer (score 13):

You should check the `download` attribute and the `window.URL` method because the `download` attribute doesn't seem to like data URI.
This [example by Google](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html) is pretty much what you are trying to do.

Comment: +1 I've tried data uri schema in the past, it works, but it decides how to name the file you end up with so its pretty much useless. I tried this in Firefox, Safari, Opera and Chrome on Mac, Safari and Opera have no "BlobBuilder" So the disclaimer about "only Chrome dev channel (14.0.835.15+) supports this attribute" is partially true. At this time it works on FireFox, it fails in Safari and Opera.

Comment: Blob Builder is supposedly working in MSIE as well... http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/BlobBuilder/

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: It seams that the page was removed in May 2020. But it still can be found in the archive few days before removal [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200508082503/http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html).

Answer (score 10):

It is not possible to save file locally without involving the local client (browser machine)  as I could be a great threat to client machine. You can use link to download that file. If you want to store something like Json data on local machine **you can use LocalStorage provided by the browsers**, [Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Thanks, it could be providing wrong information but I did not know this before and used to take help from it. Could be please tell me what is wrong in the particular link I have given in the answer.

Comment: Thx!!!
Now i studying Web storage but There are other types of conversion beyond data:application/x-json;base64?

Comment: Uao ROdneyrehm I did not know of this site wfools.com

Answer (score 7):

The possible ways to create and save files in Javascript are:

Use a library called FileSaver

```
saveAs(new File(["CONTENT"], "demo.txt", {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"}));
```

Create a blob object and offer a “save as”.

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["CONTENT"], {type: "text/plain"}));
a.download = "demo.txt";
a.click();
```

Upload the data, save it on the server.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("upfile", new Blob(["CONTENT"], {type: "text/plain"}));
fetch("SERVER.SCRIPT", { method: "POST", body: data });
```

Create a writable file stream.

```
const fileHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker();
const fileStream = await fileHandle.createWritable();
await fileStream.write(new Blob(["CONTENT"], {type: "text/plain"}));
await fileStream.close();
```

In NodeJS, simply use the file system module

```
 require("fs").writeFile("demo.txt", "Foo bar!");
```

---

```
<!-- (A) LOAD FILE SAVER -->
<!-- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/FileSaver.js -->
<!-- https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.5/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
// (B) "SAVE AS"
var myFile = new File(["CONTENT"], "demo.txt", {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(myFile);
</script>
```

---

```
// (A) CREATE BLOB OBJECT
var myBlob = new Blob(["CONTENT"], {type: "text/plain"});

// (B) CREATE DOWNLOAD LINK
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.href = url;
anchor.download = "demo.txt";
    
// (C) "FORCE DOWNLOAD"
// NOTE: MAY NOT ALWAYS WORK DUE TO BROWSER SECURITY
// BETTER TO LET USERS CLICK ON THEIR OWN
anchor.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
document.removeChild(anchor);
```

---

```
    <script>
    function blobajax () {
      // (A) CREATE BLOB OBJECT
      var myBlob = new Blob(["CONTENT"], {type: "text/plain"});
    
      // (B) FORM DATA
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append("upfile", myBlob);
    
      // (C) AJAX UPLOAD TO SERVER
      fetch("3b-upload.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
      })
      .then((res) => { return res.text(); })
      .then((txt) => { console.log(txt); });
    }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="blobajax()"/>
```

---

```
    <script>
    async function saveFile() {
      // (A) CREATE BLOB OBJECT
      var myBlob = new Blob(["CONTENT"], {type: "text/plain"});
     
      // (B) FILE HANDLER & FILE STREAM
      const fileHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker({
        types: [{
          description: "Text file",
          accept: {"text/plain": [".txt"]}
        }]
      });
      const fileStream = await fileHandle.createWritable();
     
      // (C) WRITE FILE
      await fileStream.write(myBlob);
      await fileStream.close();
    }
    </script>
    
    <input type="button" value="Save File" onclick="saveFile()"/>
```

---

```
// (A) LOAD FILE SYSTEM MODULE
// https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html
const fs = require("fs");

// (B) WRITE TO FILE
fs.writeFile("demo.txt", "CONTENT", "utf8", (error, data) => {
  console.log("Write complete");
  console.log(error);
  console.log(data);
});

/* (C) READ FROM FILE
fs.readFile("demo.txt", "utf8", (error, data) => {
  console.log("Read complete");
  console.log(error);
  console.log(data);
});
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what you are trying to achieve with "saving locally". Do you want to allow the user to download the file? then [`<a download>`](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download) is the way to go. Do you want to save it locally, so you can restore your application state? Then you might want to look into the various options of [WebStorage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage). Specifically [localStorage](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/) or [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB). The [FilesystemAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File_API/File_System_API) allows you to create local virtual file systems you can store arbitrary data in.

Comment: thx but There are other types of conversion beyond data:application/x-json;base64?

Comment: Aside from the fact that it should be [`application/json`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/515124) - no, I don't see what else would make sense.

Comment: With IndexedDB how to downloadable local?

Comment: IndexedDB is not meant to be a downloadable file. It's a database within your browser. It is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

So, your *real* question is: "How can JavaScript save to a local file?"

Take a look at http://www.tiddlywiki.com/

They save their HTML page locally after you have "changed" it internally.

[ UPDATE 2016.01.31 ]

TiddlyWiki original version saved directly.  It was quite nice, and saved to a configurable backup directory with the timestamp as part of the backup filename.

TiddlyWiki current version just downloads it as any file download.  You need to do your own backup management. :(

[ END OF UPDATE

The trick is, you have to open the page as file:// not as http:// to be able to save locally.

The security on your browser will not let you save to _someone_else's_ local system, only to your own, and even then it isn't trivial.

-Jesse

Comment: Now I studying Tiddlywiki but There are other types of conversion beyond data:application/x-json;base64?

Comment: tiddlywiki uses a java applet to access the local filesystem, not javascript.

Comment: TiddlyWiki uses a Java applet for Safari and Opera. For IE it uses ActiveX and for Firefox/Camino it uses pure javascript (via privilegeManager) or a firefox extension (since privilegeManager was removed in v15).

Comment: This jQuery plugin is extracted from TiddlyWiki, it works how @dwurf explained it. http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html

Answer (score 2):

While most despise Flash, it is a viable option for providing "save" and "save as" functionality in your html/javascript environment.

I've created a widget called "OpenSave" that provides this functionality available here:

http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/opensave/

-mike

Comment: is it possible to save everything in the head and body tags using this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FireFox you can use the File HandleAPI

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_Handle_API

I had just tested it out and it works!