# Interface between a web based tool and Matlab

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, matlab, openstreetmap

I am designing a web based tool using HTML, CSS and Javascript.
I am able to export Data from OpenStreetMap as an .OSM file using this query:

```
var osmURL = 'http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox='+a+','+b+','+c+','+d;
window.location.assign(osmURL);
```

After downloading this osm file I want to send it to Matlab and do some computational algorithms on it. How can I save this downloaded file in a place then send it to Matlab and run the needed m.files..

How can I do this link between the Web based tool and Matlab? is it feasible ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need this functionality at a webfrontend side, but this will help, as it's not OSM dependand: [How can JavaScript save to a local file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071473/how-can-javascript-save-to-a-local-file)

Please be aware that you trigger on the official read/write API that is designed esp. for interacting/editing/... OSM data and not for bulk downloading
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_usage_policy
You might want to use the OverpassAPI or a local OSM Planet dump/extract instead to do your processing.