# Saving image to local storage from canvas

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to save to file from canvas, but cannot **name** the file, this works but saves a file as "download" I would like give it any name. Any help is appreciated, lc.getImage gets image from canvas.

```
  $('#download_btn').click(function() {
     var image = lc.getImage();
     document.location.href = image.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  });
```

Comment: Check out these 2 links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071473/how-can-javascript-save-to-a-local-file

Comment: and this: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html