# nodejs sendFile return string or file contents

Tags: node.js, download, feathersjs

i use feathersjs on my backend and i encountered the problem of downloading files: look to my code

```
app.get('/download',(req,res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(app.get('public'), 'output.xlsx'));
});
```

and in response of browser i see [image]
i try to send example package.json and this is result:

[image]

i try to use `res.download()` but the result is the same. Why i can not download file on my browser?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to save a file locally is to craft a link for the download that when clicked returns the file bytes with the Content-Disposition set to be attachment as specified in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition and the download attribute set on the anchor.

Javascript cannot save files to a users computer**

**Refer to [How can JavaScript save to a local file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071473/how-can-javascript-save-to-a-local-file)